# Activar un Input con un Checkbox, con ID dado mediante Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Estoy haciendo un programa con Python y Flask, donde se toman productos de una BDD y estos tienen que ser mostrados en una pagina. La idea es que cuando el mozo selecciona el producto mediante un checkbox, al lado de precio unitario deberia aparecer un input para introducir la cantidad de el producto que se requiere

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez seleccionado, no logro que apareza el input. He probado varias formas pero aun no lo puedo lograr

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo el codigo que tengo hasta ahora.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
           function comprobar(prod){   
                document.getElementById(prod).readOnly = !document.getElementById(prod).checked;  
            }
    </script>


{% for producto in productos %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="items_a_pedir" 
            value="{{ producto.Nombre }}" id="{{ producto.Nombre }}" onclick="comprobar({{ producto.Nombre }});"/>
        </td>

        <td align= "left"><label for="{{ producto.Nombre }}" >{{ producto.Nombre }}</label></td>
        <td> ${{ producto.PrecioUnitario }} </td>    

        <td><input type="number" id= "{{ producto.Nombre }}" name="cantidad" class="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad" readonly style="display:none"></td>

    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Agradeceria mucho si me pueden dar una mano. Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo optaría por algo simple, dado que todos los checkbox realizan la misma acción y solo dependen del producto entonces podemos hacer una selección por clases, una vez seleccionado los elementos que tengan una misma clase, le agregaremos un `EventListener` para poder escuchar cuando den click al checkbox (incluso puedes hacer una comprobación) posteriormente obtenemos su valor y buscamos a un input que tenga ese `id` para mostrarlo.

```py
{% for producto in productos %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="items_a_pedir" value="{{ producto.Nombre }}" class="producto"/>
        </td>

        <td align= "left"><label for="{{ producto.Nombre }}" >{{ producto.Nombre }}</label></td>
        <td> ${{ producto.PrecioUnitario }} </td>    

        <td><input type="number" id="{{ producto.Nombre }}" name="cantidad" class="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad" style="display:none"></td>

    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Y en tu JavaScript harías esto

```js
let productos = document.getElementsByClassName("producto");    

for (let i=0; i< productos.length; i++) {
    //Añadimos un evento a cada elemento
    productos[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
       let cantId = document.getElementById(this.value)
       cantId.style.display = "block" //mostramos el elemento
    });
}
```

Recuerda que la etiqueta `script` que enlaza o agrega el Javascript debe ir al último (antes de cerrar la etiqueta `html`) para no tener problemas.

Comment: Hola Christian! Muchas gracias por responder. Intente hacerlo como me lo marcaste pero aun no puedo hacerlo funcionar. Me sigue sin mostrar el input para ingresar una cantidad

Comment: te aparece algún error en la consola??

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: me faltó una llave

Comment: prueba nuevamente

Comment: Me anduvo perfecto! Mil gracias. Hay alguna forma de que aparezca y desaparezca al apretar el checkbox? Porque en este caso una vez que se selecciona, el input ya queda por siempre sin importar si selecciono o no el checkbox

Comment: puedes hacer `cantId.style.display = this.checked ? "block":"none"`

Comment: te quiero mucho

Answer (score 0):

Tenes dos modos.

- O bien pones todos los *input* donde quieres que aparezcan con un *id* determinado. Algo como

```
<input type="number" id="cant_pizza_muzzarella" value="1" style="display:none" />
```

y en la funcion **comprobar()** haces algo como:

```
document.getElementById("cant_pizza_muzzarella").style.display="block"
```

- O bien pones un *div* vacío con `display:inline` al lado del precio y lo llenas con el *input* `type="number"`. En el script que lo reciba en un caso vas a tener todos los campos vacios menos los que el mozo complete y en el otro solo aquellos que el mozo habilite.

Comment: Tu respuesta ha llegado a revisión por algún reporte. ten en cuenta que para que tu respuesta sea completa y aceptada, debes añadir el código con el que se soluciona el problema. Puedes leer más acerca de esto en [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](/help/how-to-answer). Adicionalmente a esto, si se vota negativamente varias veces desde revisión tu respuesta puede quedar eliminada. Saludos.